# My question is about Google Tag Manager, but there's no tag for it yet

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I asked this question a while back:

- [Google Tag Manager no longer in preview mode for any version](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/49564/11354).

At first it was tagged with `[google]`, but that tag was removed later by someone else. There's no tag for `[google-tag-manager]`, and I don't have enough rep to create it yet.

Can someone create it for me please? So that I may tag my question properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added the tag. The system periodically deletes one-off used tags, so that may explain why it got deleted

Comment: Does this mean that if no one else posts another Google Tag Manager question, that the tag could get deleted again? Is this just not the right [se] site to post such a question to?

Comment: @Cupcake The tag gets deleted if it's used only once in 6 months. Presence/absence of a tag doesn't necessarily imply whether a particular topic is offtopic, just could be not many people use it or haven't found a question about it to ask